# Is there any way to set window size in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

In Chrome, for example, in developer mode, you can press the Toggle device toolbar (Ctrl + Shift + M). And then indicate the window size above, for example: 483 x 250. Is it possible to do something similar in IE?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that you want to set the resolution. In the IE browser, you could set it by using [the F12 developer Emulation tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255001(v=vs.85)), screenshot as below:

[image]